# Структурировать большой объем текста

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл (несколько десятков тысяч строк), где разными людьми в произвольном виде заполнены адреса (регион, индекс, город, улица, дом и т.д.)

Например:

```
"50-Московская область, р-н Чеховский, 142327, г Чехов, п/о Чернецкое, ул Победы, 18вг"

"г. Свободный, ул. Ремесленная-38",Владимирская область
```

Нужно выделить отдельные столбцы с городами, улицами и номером дома

Есть неполные списки городов и улиц.
Какой наиболее простой способ?

Comment: Эм.. Да никакого. Попытаться скормить адреса в api какой-нибудь онлайн-карты и посмотреть, как она их распарсит.

Comment: https://dadata.ru/suggestions/#address

Answer (score 0):

Использовать сервис [dadata](https://dadata.ru/suggestions/#address), имеет простое API, понимает адрес в любом виде.

Или юзать yandex/google geocode

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку [natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha), см. статью на Хабре: [Наташа — библиотека для извлечения структурированной информации из текстов на русском языке](https://habr.com/ru/post/349864)

Конкретно с вашими данными как есть справляется не очень хорошо, например из первого примера выделяет только улицу и номер дома:

```
from natasha import AddressExtractor
from natasha.markup import show_markup, show_json

extractor = AddressExtractor()

text = "50-Московская область, р-н Чеховский, 142327, г Чехов, п/о Чернецкое, ул Победы, 18вг"

matches = extractor(text)
spans = [_.span for _ in matches]
facts = [_.fact.as_json for _ in matches]
show_markup(text, spans)
show_json(facts)
```

Вывод:

```
50-Московская область, р-н Чеховский, 142327, г Чехов, п/о Чернецкое, [[ул Победы, 18]]вг
[
  {
    "parts": [
      {
        "name": "Победы",
        "type": "улица"
      },
      {
        "number": "18"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Если убрать п/о (почтовое отделение, как я понял) и р-н поставить после названия района, то результат будет немного лучше:

```
50-[[Московская область, Чеховский р-н, 142327, г Чехов, ул Победы, 18]]вг
[
  {
    "parts": [
      {
        "name": "Московская",
        "type": "область"
      },
      {
        "name": "Чеховский",
        "type": "район"
      },
      {
        "value": "142327"
      },
      {
        "name": "Чехов",
        "type": "город"
      },
      {
        "name": "Победы",
        "type": "улица"
      },
      {
        "number": "18"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Из второго примера данные вытащит если перевести в такой формат:

```
Владимирская область, г. Свободный, ул. Ремесленная 38
```

Результат:

```
[[Владимирская область, г. Свободный, ул. Ремесленная 38]]
[
  {
    "parts": [
      {
        "name": "Владимирская",
        "type": "область"
      },
      {
        "name": "Свободный",
        "type": "город"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ремесленная",
        "type": "улица"
      },
      {
        "number": "38"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Можно сделать свой вариант экстрактора на основе Yargi-парсера (входит в ту же библиотеку), пример написания парсера есть в статье на хабре. Или доработать существующий парсер: https://github.com/natasha/natasha/blob/master/natasha/grammars/address.py